# python find matching strings in log file

Tags: python-3.x

I have two files which I am working with, one contains a list of user names.

```
$cat user.txt
johnsmith
MikeSmith
```

```
$cat logfile 
root@host1 : /home/johnsmith
root@host2 : /home/johnsmith
root@host3 : /home/MikeSmith
```

The log *logfile*, contains a dump of different configs of systems across multiple hosts, it also includes home directory of users if any in following pattern.

How can I iterate through *user.txt* and find/match any/all lines which contains username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:**

```
# Read User file
f = open("user.txt", "r")
names = f.read().split() # List of user names
f.close()
# Read Log file
f = open("logfile", "r") # List of log lines
log_lines = f.read().split('\n')
f.close()

for i, log in enumerate(log_lines):
    for name in names:
        if name in log:
            print(name + ' is present in line ' + str(i + 1))
```

**Output:**

```
johnsmith is present in line 1
johnsmith is present in line 2
MikeSmith is present in line 3
```

Comment: Thanks, code worked as it supposed to I am trying to implement endswith* in last if statement as its picking up some unexpected values from logfile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how you want to use your user list, but I guess this can be used to raise an error when the user doesn't appear in it. This would save the cost of searching for non-existing user logs.

```py
import re

with open("user.txt") as f:
    users = set(f.read().splitlines())

config_pattern = re.compile(r"[^@]*@[\w]*\s*:\s*\/home\/(\w*)")

def find_user_configs(user_name):
    # We don't bother reading the file if the user doesn't exist:
    if user_name not in users:
        raise ValueError(f"User {user_name} doesn't exist.")

    with open("logfile") as f:
        for line in f:
            match = config_pattern.search(line)
            if match and match.groups()[0] == user_name:
                yield line.strip()


print(list(find_user_configs("johnsmith")))
```

This will print the list of configs for `johnsmith`:

```py
['root@host1 : /home/johnsmith', 'root@host2 : /home/johnsmith']
```

Note that depending on your needs it may be smart to put all the log in memory instead of reading them from disk every time `find_user_configs`.

Comment: Thank you @cglacet, end goal is to create a output file which gives user audit details:
`host1 : johnsmith
host1: mikesmith
host2: johnsmith
..
..
`